# Unrecognized arguments to Dictionary constructor

Tags: google-earth-engine

My goal is to create collection of multi-band images, where each band is a constant number value which I've calculated in previous steps. It appears I'm constructing the dictionary incorrectly, however, and I'm not sure why.

```
var number = 1.11
var another_number = 0.55
var AOI = ee.Geometry.Point([-41.01603606041101, -16.378051869127507]);

var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
           .filterBounds(AOI).filterDate('2018-01-01', '2019-01-01');

var col = imageCollection.map(function (image) {
      var time = image.get('system:time_start');
      var median = ee.Number(number);
      var median_image = ee.Image(median).double();
      var sd = ee.Number(another_number);
      var sd_image = ee.Image(sd).double();
      return ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([median_image, sd_image])
                     .toBands().set(time);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of your `set` function is wrong, if you change it to `.set({time:time});` (or whichever property name you would like for "time") then it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Of course I overlooked the fact that the .set() method takes a key/value pair as argument.